# conditional hashpling in LINUX text scripts

Tags: linux, process, conditional-statements

As a workaround for a problem that I face when deploying code using central version control throughout various sites in the company I work, I need, in all sites, to run Ruby from (say):

```
#!/foo1/bin/ruby -w
```

However, in just 1 location, ude to an I.T. issue, which may or may not be resolved, I need to use (say):

```
#!/foo2/bin/ruby -w
```

This needs to work for ALL users in ALL sites, and I cannot enforce the setup of environment variables. One can of course, use a bash script to split the 2, (a bash script calling either of the locations), but I was hoping for just 1 process, and 1 script. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

There are many options to solve that but the simples that I'm familair with is:

1. Make sure that ruby is accesible by the PATH environment variable.
2. Instad of using the full path to ruby you can use the /bin/env command that comes in all Linux bundles:

   ```
   #!/bin/env ruby
   ```